# Zoom to specified markers react-native-maps

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, react-native, maps, apple-maps

There is a section in the [react-native-maps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps#zoom-to-specified-markers) docs for zooming to an array of markers, however there are no code examples on how to do this either in the docs or in the examples folder (from what I can find)

Can anyone provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/FitToSuppliedMarkers.js  this seems to be an example of Zoom to Array.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the MapView component docs, there are a few methods: `fitToElements`, `fitToSuppliedMarkers` and `fitToCoordinates`. https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#methods

If you want to zoom the map in on some collection of markers on load, you can use `componentDidMount` to zoom in after the initial render:

```
class SomeView extends Component {
    constructor() {
      this.mapRef = null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.mapRef.fitToSuppliedMarkers(
        someArrayOfMarkers,
        false, // not animated
      );
    }

    render() {
      <MapView
        ref={(ref) => { this.mapRef = ref }}
      >
        { someArrayOfMarkers }
      </MapView>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but how would I change the zoom distance? Currently it is so far zoomed out all of the markers appear to be on top of each other.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I'm an idiot. Thanks again.

Comment: @denisw you pass latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta to the coords object, a value of 0.02 for both equals a few blocks.

Comment: what is someArrayOfMarkers here..? @luke Berry

Comment: @LukeBerry someArrayOfMarkers should look like: [
{latitude: 36.193852, longitude: 43.964365},
{latitude: 36.170168, longitude: 44.02348},
{latitude: 36.202618, longitude: 44.035115}
 ]

Comment: This doesn't zoom for me though.  It just centers the map around the markers.  How do you make it actually zoom in or out to fit all the markers on the screen?

Comment: @LukeEhresman just add on the `<Map />` the `initialRegion={{
          latitude: 0,
          longitude: 0,
          latitudeDelta: 0.015,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
        }}`

With your own values, this sets the initial zoom and after the markers are loaded the script will fit them